# how to take value from fetched JSON Object and show it in react

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch

I fetch data from WordPress to react. If data comes in array format I can fetch it, show the content, and map it. But when it comes to JSON Object, I have problems showing the parts I want and also I cannot map it.

my json object simplified = http://myname/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/2

```
{
  "id": 2,
  "date": "",
  "guid": {
    "rendered": ""
  },
  "content": {
    "rendered": "\n<p>Dit is een voorbeeldpagina. Gevestigd in Gotham City, XYZ heeft meer dan 2000 mensen in dienst en doen allemaal fantastische dingen voor de community in Gotham.</p>",
    "protected": false
  },
  
  "_links": {
    "self": [
      {
        "href": "..."
      }
    ],
    "collection": [
      {
        "href": "..."
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

my useFetch component

```
export default function useFetch(url) {
    const [data, setData] = useState([]);
    useEffect(() => {
        async function loadData() {
            const response = await fetch(url);
            if(!response.ok) {
                // oups! something went wrong
                return;
            }
    
            const posts = await response.json();
            setData(posts);
        }
        
        loadData();
        
    }, [url]);
    return data;

}
```

the component I want to show the data

```
function Page(props) {

  const voorbeeldpagina = useFetch(
    "http://myname/wp-json/wp/v2/pages/2"
  );

  // const newArray = Object.entries(voorbeeldpagina)
  // I have also tried OBject.keys and Object.values 
  

return (
    <div>
      <h1>Page Component</h1>
      <div> {**I want to show `content.rendered` from my json object**} </div>
    </div>
  )
}
```

**I want to show `content.rendered` from my json object**
can anyone help?

Thanks!

Comment: Please add the error message you are getting.

Answer (score 0):

well you are trying to map an object you can use object.keys to map them.

```
Object.keys(posts).map((key)=>return(  
 //your code goes here
 )
```